# How I can modify the following code to get the result of an array with shortest length?

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, sorting, pyspark, struct

How I can modify the following code:

```py
c1_arr = F.col('col1')
c2_arr = F.split(F.trim('col2'), '\s+')
arr_of_struct = F.transform(
    c1_arr,
    lambda x: F.struct(
        F.size(F.array_intersect(c2_arr, F.split(F.trim(x), '\s+'))).alias('cnt'),
        x.alias('val'),
    )
)
top_val = F.sort_array(arr_of_struct, False)[0]
```

`top_val` gives me an element of `col1` where it has the most common token with `col2`'s element. I want to get an element of `col1` where it has the most common token with `col2`'s element and it has the shortest length or token.

For example consider the following data:

```
col1              col2
["come and get", "computer", come and get more" ]       "come for good"
["summer is hot", "summer is too hot", "hot weather"]       "hot tea"
["summer is hot", "summer is too hot", "hot weather"]       "hot summer"
```

Desired output:

```
col1              col2                                                          match
["come and get", "computer", come and get more" ]       "come for good"         "come and get"
["summer is hot", "summer is too hot", "hot weather"]       "hot tea"           "hot weather"
["summer is hot", "summer is too hot", "hot weather"]       "hot summer"       "summer is hot"
```

Then I use the following code to get my desired result:

```
df = df.select(
    '*',
    F.when(((top_val['cnt'] > 1) & (F.size(c2_arr) > 1))|((top_val['cnt'] > 0) & (F.size(c2_arr) == 1))|((F.size(F.split(F.trim(top_val['val']),'\s+'))==1) &(top_val['cnt']>0 )),top_val['val']).alias('match'))
```

The first condition says that the match will be selected if the intersection is more than 1 and the size of co2 is also larger than 1.

the second condition says that if the size of `col2` is equal 1 then intersection needs to be non-zero

And the third condition says if the intersection is 1 and an element of col1 is also equal to one, the element is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, input:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(["come and get", "computer", "come and get more"], "come for good"),
     (["summer is hot", "summer is too hot", "hot weather"], "hot tea"),
     (["summer is hot", "summer is too hot", "hot weather"], "hot summer")],
    ['col1', 'col2'])
```

For the answer, along the process, I've made 2 options...

---

You'll want to use this option, because it is way cleaner. In order to make both struct fields sort *ascending*, I've added the `-` sign before the count of matching tokens. When both field order direction is the same, the code does not need much alterations:

```py
c1_arr = F.col('col1')
c2_arr = F.split(F.trim('col2'), '\s+')
arr_of_struct = F.transform(
    c1_arr,
    lambda x: F.struct(
        F.size(F.array_intersect(c2_arr, F.split(F.trim(x), '\s+'))).alias('cnt'),
        (-F.size(F.split(F.trim(x), '\s+'))).alias('len'),
        x.alias('val'),
    )
)
top_val = F.sort_array(arr_of_struct, False)[0]
df = df.withColumn('match', top_val.val)

df.show(truncate=0)
# +-----------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+
# |col1                                           |col2         |match        |
# +-----------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+
# |[come and get, computer, come and get more]    |come for good|come and get |
# |[summer is hot, summer is too hot, hot weather]|hot tea      |hot weather  |
# |[summer is hot, summer is too hot, hot weather]|hot summer   |summer is hot|
# +-----------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+
```

---

Option #2 - *for academic use* ;)

Make results sorted on:

1. one struct's field - descending
2. other struct's field - ascending

Since order directions are different, I've created the custom sorting function (so-called *comparator function*). It looks at "cnt" field of the struct (and sorts descending). But if "cnt" field values are equal, then the function looks at "len" field (and sorts ascending).

```py
c1_arr = F.col('col1')
c2_arr = F.split(F.trim('col2'), '\s+')
df = df.withColumn(
    'match',
    F.transform(
        c1_arr,
        lambda x: F.struct(
            F.size(F.array_intersect(c2_arr, F.split(F.trim(x), '\s+'))).alias('cnt'),
            F.size(F.split(F.trim(x), '\s+')).alias('len'),
            x.alias('val'),
        )
    )
)
df = df.withColumn('match', F.expr("""
    array_sort(
        match,
        (l, r) -> case when l.cnt > r.cnt then -1
                       when l.cnt < r.cnt then 1
                       when l.len < r.len then -1
                       when l.len > r.len then 1
                       else 0
                  end)
    """)[0].val)

df.show(truncate=0)
# +-----------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+
# |col1                                           |col2         |match        |
# +-----------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+
# |[come and get, computer, come and get more]    |come for good|come and get |
# |[summer is hot, summer is too hot, hot weather]|hot tea      |hot weather  |
# |[summer is hot, summer is too hot, hot weather]|hot summer   |summer is hot|
# +-----------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+
```

We can only do this in SQL API, because `array_sort` in Python API does not have the function parameter.

Comment: `Error: AnalysisException: Can't extract value from sort_array(transform(clean_company_name1#688, lambdafunction(struct(col1, -size(array_intersect(split(trim(clean_company_name#882, None), \s+, -1), split(trim(lambda x_15#901, None), \s+, -1)), true) AS cnt#897, len, size(split(trim(lambda x_15#901, None), \s+, -1), true) AS len#898, val, lambda x_15#901 AS val#899), lambda x_15#901, false)), false)[0].val: need struct type but got string`

Comment: `top_val` variable was removed. Now you should get 'match' column like you want. You don't need that other condition as far as I can understand. Please design questions more carefully. You showed the desired output, and the code does exactly that.

Comment: I have returned the `top_val` variable and changed the order to Descending (in Option #1), so that it would match the previous situation. Try now please.

Comment: Actually I tried this before and I got error: `AnalysisException: No such struct field cnt in col1, len, val`

Comment: Try now, I have changed this issue (the `-` should have been inside parentheses)